# Create table returns error 1064 syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this code to create a table inside of a db. Seems correct, but I'm getting a syntax error. I'm using the syntax directly from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html but no cigar. Ideas?

```
create table car (
VIN integer primary key autoincrement, 
make text not null, 
model text not null, 
year text not null);
```

Comment: Ah. Rookie mistake. Thanks, I've been up way too long, I appreciate it.

Comment: When you get mysql syntax errors, always take care or reading the "to use near..." part of the message; it will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: it's `auto_increment` not `autoincrement`.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in auto increment syntax.

Use this:

```
create table car (
VIN integer  primary key auto_increment, 
make text not null, 
model text not null, 
year text not null);
```

More: [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table car (
   VIN integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   make text not null, 
   model text not null, 
   year text not null
);
```

Should work